# How to get the last element of an array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, indexing

The [PostgreSQL Documentation on arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/arrays.html) provides an example using `[-1]` to access what appears to be the last element of an array; however while `SELECT arr[2:3];` produces `{5,9}`, `arr[2:-1]` results in `{}`.

How can the last element of an array be obtained in PostgreSQL?

Edit: Windows, PostgreSQL v9.2.1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting the example. PostgreSQL arrays don't have to be indexed from 1 to `n`, [that's just the default](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING):

> By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of ***n*** elements starts with `array[1]` and ends with `array[n]`.

The example you're looking at is this:

```
SELECT f1[1][-2][3] AS e1, f1[1][-1][5] AS e2
 FROM (SELECT '[1:1][-2:-1][3:5]={{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}}'::int[] AS f1) AS ss;
```

But those negative numbers aren't indexing from the end of the arrays as in languages such as Perl. In the `FROM (SELECT ...` part, they're specifying the starting and ending indexes so the -1 in `f1[1][-1][5]` is just a plain old index. Consider this [`array_dims`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) result:

```
=> SELECT array_dims('[1:1][-2:-1][3:5]={{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}}'::int[]);
    array_dims     
-------------------
 [1:1][-2:-1][3:5]
```

If you're using the default 1-based arrays then you can get the last element with a simple `arr[array_length(arr, 1)]`. If you're not using the default `[1:n]` arrays then you'll have to mess around with [`array_lower`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and [`array_upper`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to get the first and last elements; or, depending on the circumstances, you might be able to use [`unnest`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) to unpack the array then work with the array as a rowset.

Answer (score 64):

For any array "arr", to fetch the last element of array arr use

```
SELECT arr[array_upper(arr, 1)];
```

Answer (score 11):

If someone is using Postgre 9.5, the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) says:

`-> int`

> Get JSON array element (indexed from zero, negative integers count from the end)

So this works for me:

```
to_json(arr)->-1
```

Comment: This works only if `arr` is of the `json` type. This does not work for PostgreSQL array types.

Comment: worked for me on an `array_agg(id)`

Comment: This answer helped me to come up with this solution:
`array_to_json(ARRAY(SELECT...))->-1`

Answer (score 2):

I have a case where I prefer not to:

- Reference the array twice [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146087/521799) (because the array is a complex array expression)
- Use a JSON workaround [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65129089/521799) (because the array can be of any non JSON compatible type)

So, another option is to use `UNNEST .. WITH ORDINALITY`:

```sql
SELECT
  a,
  (
    SELECT v 
    FROM unnest(a) 
    WITH ORDINALITY AS t (v, o) 
    ORDER BY o DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  )
FROM (VALUES (ARRAY[1, 3, 2])) AS t (a)
```

Producing:

```
|a      |v  |
|-------|---|
|{1,3,2}|2  |
```

Of course, assuming there is no clever optimisation for the combination of `WITH ORDINALITY` and `LIMIT 1`, this will find the last array element in `O(N log N)` (due to the sort) in the worst case, rather than `O(1)`, but sometimes, arrays are small enough, and sometimes, there isn't any other way.