# Order a SELECT by the first element of an array?

Tags: postgresql

I have an array of strings as one of my columns, and I want to sort the result by the first element of the array. This is what I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY aliases[0];
```

This did not work. How may this be accomplished?

Comment: For better way https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766076/2430102

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Arrays in Postgres are indexed beginning at position 1, not 0.  From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html):

> By default PostgreSQL uses a one-based numbering convention for arrays, that is, an array of n elements starts with array[1] and ends with array[n].

With this in mind, try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY aliases[1];
```

Comment: That is the default form, but it is not strictly so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12766076/2430102