# How to filter based on the last element in ArrayField in django

Tags: arrays, django, postgresql

I'm using postgresql database which allows having an array datatype, in addition django provides PostgreSQL specific model fields for that. 
My question is how can I filter objects based on the last element of the array?

```
class Example(models.Model):
     tags = ArrayField(models.CharField(...))
example = Example.objects.create(tags=['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
example_tag3 = Example.objects.filter(tags__2='tag3')
```

I want to filter but don't know what is the size of the tags. Is there any dynamic filtering something like:

```
example_tag3 = Example.objects.filter(tags__last='tag3')
```

Comment: I understand what you're asking but I'm not sure why you would do anything this way.  Ways to do this probably involve returning the length of the array into a variable on save and then using the variable as a filter.

Comment: I'm using arrayField to store kind of history of a variable I'm interested in, so I want to get all records that have the last value as x.
The problem that each record may have different number of elements in what I've called tags. So looping for all objects and get the length of tags will kill the performance

Comment: I think you’re going to have to do a raw SQL query to get the array length and use that in your filter.  Someone else probably knows better than I but that’s my best suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do that without "killing the performance" other than using raw SQL ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146087/2528658)). But you should avoid doing things like this, from [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html):

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.

Comment: Well, yeah I think you are right, I read all docs but could not find what I need, 
So, to solved my problem by storing the elements in a reversed way by prepending elements into the array instead of appending them, 
Then I did the filtering by checking the first element (which is supported) :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the above answer and comment, if changing the table structure isn't an option, you may filter your query based on the **first** element in an array by using `field__0`:

```
example_tag3 = Example.objects.filter(tags__0='tag1')
```

However, I don't see a way to access the last element directly [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#index-transforms).